# Java take range from array

Tags: java, arrays, scala, syntax

Does Java have a method of Array drop? 
In Scala we have: `Array.drop(10).take(16)` or maybe to take a range of members of an array?

 In Java I can only do `array[10]` for example.

Comment: Lists would be much easier to manipulate in this way.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon agreed. Lists can provide (readable) views on sub lists via `List::subList`, thus eliminating the need for duplicating the backing data structure like you would need for an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `Arrays::copyOfRange`:

It has three parameters:

- `original`: the source array
- `from`: the starting index, inclusive
- `to`: the end index, exclusive

Not that it returns a new array, meaning that if you change the values of the resulting array, the original array does not change.

The method is overloaded to work for all primitive types and for objects.

Here's an example use:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] source = IntStream.range(0, 10).toArray()
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(source));

        final int[] result = Arrays.copyOfRange(source, 3, 8);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

For more information, see [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easiest to achieve such semantics by streaming the array:

```
SomeClass[] sourceArray = /* something */;

SomeClass[] result = 
    Arrays.stream(sourceArray).skip(10L).limit(16L).toArray(SomeClass[]::new);
```

Comment: Personally I think `Arrays::copyOfRange` is more concise and to the point, and presumably has much better performance.

Comment: @Marv I agree it's more concise, but it does leave a lot of error/edge-case handling to the user.

Comment: Good point, but I wouldn't use this anywhere near a performance critical situation. I just did a quick benchmark with JMH and the `Arrays::copyOfRange` version came out to be about 200 times faster.

Comment: Equivalent to Scala or the Java Streams solution: `static <T> T[] dropN_takeM(T[] array, int drop, int take) { return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, Math.min(drop, array.length), Math.max(drop+take, array.length));}`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You're gonna have to take another look at that. For an Array of length 3, `dropN_takeM(arr, 10, 20)` returns an array of `27` null values. I'd take an exception over that any day of the week! I think `max` also needs to be `min` for it to work.

Comment: @Marv you're right. That should be `static <T> T[] dropN_takeM(T[] array, int drop, int take) { return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, Math.min(drop, array.length), Math.min(drop+take, array.length));}`. (max should be min)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use the first. And thanks for another way!